# How to read outlook group emails with microsoft graph api?

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Is there any way to read mails from group email id or is there any way to read emails without graph api?

And also is there any way to restrict graph api token to read only from desired email account?

Comment: Hi Kiran, do you have chance to look into my answer? If you have any further question, please fee l free to let me know. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: yes Allen, i have gone through your answer tried also, but not working as expected

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the error message? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GET /users/{id of group email}/mailFolders/{id}/messages` to read mails from  group email id.

See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

If you want to restrict graph api token to read only from desired email account, you should implement [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0). Then you will be able to access the signed-in user's email only.

Comment: Please don't use EWS. It has been de-emphasized and will be deprecated. I'll edit this answer.

Comment: The documentation clearly says GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders/{id}/messages.
You cannot access a group with this endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the following call will get you the emails in a group mailbox.
`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/conversations`

Can you ask your second question in a new post as it is not related to the first? Make sure you provide information about what you are doing. What auth flow are you using?